# Multiply Node not adding

Tags: texturing

[image: pitch black problem1]

I want to mix the color ramp shader with a voronoi shader, but when I try to add them, it just becomes pitch black. I am using Blender 3.4. Can anyone help me solve my problem?

Comment: You use *multiply* mix mode. It makes colors darker. To add colors, use *screen* or *add*

Comment: Thanks for your help, mate!